# Spring Boot 1 - Reload with Bootstrap Selected Tab

Tags: jquery, spring, spring-boot

I have a web page that has several Bootstrap tabs and when I post the form I want to be able to get back to tab that was selected instead of returning to the first tab.

So for the example below I have only created 2 tabs and am wanting to post a form on the second tab "Add Item". I want to be able to return to the "Add Item" if the add item form is posted.  I guess I need to set the specific tab on the ModelAndView but don't know how to do this.

Controller:

```
@PostMapping("/add/new/item")
public ModelAndView addNewItem(ModelAndView modelAndView, HttpServletRequest request, 
        @Valid @ModelAttribute NewItemForm newItemForm, BindingResult bindingResult
        ) {

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors() || newItemForm == null) {
        //Log errors
    } else {
        //Add item
    }
    return new ModelAndView(
       new RedirectView(ITEMS_URL, false),
       modelAndView.getModel()
    );

}
```

```js
if ($('.nav-tabs a')) {
  var url = document.location.toString();
  if (url.match('#')) {
    $('.nav-tabs a[href="#' + url.split('#')[1] + '"]').tab('show');
  }

  // Change hash for page-reload
  $('.nav-tabs a').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e) {
    window.location.hash = e.target.hash;
  })
}
```

```css
.panel.with-nav-tabs.panel-tab-block {
  box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
}

.with-nav-tabs.panel-tab-block .nav-tabs>li>a,
.with-nav-tabs.panel-tab-block .nav-tabs>li>a:hover,
.with-nav-tabs.panel-tab-block .nav-tabs>li>a:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #999999;
}

.with-nav-tabs.panel-tab-block .nav-tabs>.open>a,
.with-nav-tabs.panel-tab-block .nav-tabs>.open>a:hover,
.with-nav-tabs.panel-tab-block .nav-tabs>.open>a:focus,
.with-nav-tabs.panel-tab-block .nav-tabs>li>a:hover,
.with-nav-tabs.panel-tab-block .nav-tabs>li>a:focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #666666;
}

.with-nav-tabs.panel-tab-block .nav-tabs>li.active>a,
.with-nav-tabs.panel-tab-block .nav-tabs>li.active>a:hover,
.with-nav-tabs.panel-tab-block .nav-tabs>li.active>a:focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #2f70b1;
  border-color: #2f70b1;
}

.with-nav-tabs.panel-tab-block .nav-tabs>li.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #428bca;
  border-color: #3071a9;
}

.with-nav-tabs.panel-tab-block .nav-tabs>li.dropdown .dropdown-menu>li>a {
  color: #fff;
}

.with-nav-tabs.panel-tab-block .nav-tabs>li.dropdown .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover,
.with-nav-tabs.panel-tab-block .nav-tabs>li.dropdown .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus {
  background-color: #3071a9;
}

.with-nav-tabs.panel-tab-block .nav-tabs>li.dropdown .dropdown-menu>.active>a,
.with-nav-tabs.panel-tab-block .nav-tabs>li.dropdown .dropdown-menu>.active>a:hover,
.with-nav-tabs.panel-tab-block .nav-tabs>li.dropdown .dropdown-menu>.active>a:focus {
  background-color: #4a9fe9;
}

.list-group-item {
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #e4e4e4;
  padding: 0.5em;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid #1d3c5c;
}

.list-group-item-title {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.list-group label {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.spacer-sml {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid portfolio-overview-container">
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <div class="panel with-nav-tabs panel-tab-block">
      <div class="panel-heading ">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
          <li><a data-toggle="tab" role="tab" class="" href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
          <li><a data-toggle="tab" role="tab" class="" href="#add-item-tab">Add Item</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="tab-content">
          <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane fade">
            <div class="tab-block-content ">
              <div class="row ">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <h1>
                    Tab 1 - Example....
                  </h1>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="add-item-tab" class="tab-pane fade">
            <form action="/add/new/item" method="POST">
              <div class="row">
                <label class="col-sm-6" for="folderName">New Item Name:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <input class="" type="text" name="newItem" required value="" />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ">Add</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have worked out a way of doing this but it feels really hacky.  Because I know which method is being called from the form submission, I can append the hardcoded tab name to the redirect view like so:

```
return new ModelAndView(
   new RedirectView(ITEMS_URL + "?#add-item-tab", false),
   modelAndView.getModel()
);
```